# How to hardcode the file name for uploading?

Tags: php, html, facebook-graph-api, file-upload, facebook-php-sdk

I cant find a relevant answer for this question in web. I am searching it for past 2 hours. Is there any way to hardcode the file name in `<input type='file' name='myfiles'>`. I don't want to select the file manually. There is a similar question in stack overflow and the answer is `Impossible.` I thought of using jquery for it but I cant find a method. Is there any way? 
I want to upload an image into facebook using graph api.

Please help.

Comment: jQuery is just a Javascript library, it doesn't add capabilities to the browser.

Comment: Just no, and there is like no logical explanation why to do that.

Comment: What if the user renames the file? How would this work portably on Windows and Unix?

Comment: I want to upload any image into facebook. The script will be executed automatically for every one hour. I just want to select the file name. That is the script should handle it.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is merely a JavaScript library. It will not give JavaScript the permission to automatically select files on the user's system. That would be a **massive** security issue. What would stop a website from scanning the user's system for sensitive documents?

Comment: I thought of submitting the form using javascript/jquery. So no way to do it?

Comment: You can submit the form via JavaScript / jQuery. But you can't automatically select the file. The user will need to do that.

Comment: @Vishnu: It would be possible with a Java applet, but Wayne has a good point here.

Comment: So how to upload a file programmatically ? Any way?

Comment: @AlixAxel Worth noting that the user would have to give the Java applet permission.

Comment: @Vishnu This depends. Will it be the exact same system that you're uploading from?

Comment: @WayneWhitty I want to upload the file to facebook using graph api.

Comment: @WayneWhitty: Of course, that pretty much goes without saying. We would be in serious trouble if it wasn't like that.

Comment: @Vishnu: There's a big difference between doing it programatically and programatically via the browser. The former is pretty simple. The latter requires Java applets (which to be truthful, it's not part of the browser) and appropriate user permissions. Either way, it's a bad idea. If you describe your need in more detail, we might be able to come up with a more realistic approach.